# requested url is invalid for this ftp command

Tags: c#

I am trying to upload a csv file to ftp location but it fails everytime with the above reason.

My code fails at: `Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://100.100.100.83");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("guardian", "roar");
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.UsePassive = false;
            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("C:/blacklists/blacklist.csv");
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its just a csv file on local system which needs to be loaded on that ftp loaction

Comment: What is the error u got?

Comment: requested url is invalid for this ftp command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem once and I replaced `"ftp://100.100.100.83/"` with `"ftp://ftp.xxx.com/"` and works fine.

your URL missing the file name,

```
ftp://100.100.100.83/blacklist.csv
```

Comment: Did the FQDN solve your problem, or the closing slash character?

Comment: @shryaj Are you sure that this URL is correct? did you try to upload manually?